# Call function new item in a sharepoint 2013 library

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, javascript

I have a list and above this library is a picture button. When I click on this button I would like to call the function which is on "new item". It should appear the form where I can upload the document with the properties

How can I trigger that?

Comment: Hey can you rephrase the question or add some pictures?

Comment: Normally in a library you can click on "new item" and then a small dialog lauches where you can upload your document. Then you need to set the document meta data (properties) I need this function on a picture. If you click on that picute/button then the same dialog should appear

Comment: Were you referring to "Upload Document" button on ribbon?

Answer (score 2):

Step 1: Click on the "Upload Document", you will get a popup

Step 2: If it is IE browser right click on popup and click on Properties and copy the full Address (URL).

Step 3: Assign the above URL to options.url in the following code

Step 4: Attach the click event to your custom button using jQuery or Javascript like below

```
$('#btnUpl').click(function(){

var options = SP.UI.$create_DialogOptions();

options.title = "My Dialog Title";
options.url = "http://YourURL/_layouts/15/Upload.aspx?List=%7B3021DE8C%2DE1E1%2D4ACC%2D9FF7%2D3F355B5038C3%7D&RootFolder=%2FDocuments&Source=http%3A%2F%2Fentd2spweb02%3A1984%2FDocuments%2FForms%2FAllItems%2Easpx&IsDlg=1";

SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options);

});
```

Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Where I get this item '#btnUpl'?

Comment: That is your button ID, you are attaching a click event to your button using jQuery with the above code snippet. If you cannot use jQuery use pure javascript. I hope you understand the base idea behind it. I tested it and it worked for me.

Comment: thank you! I get the idea, but can I use only the script editor for performing this?